# SCCM cmdlets have case sensitive properties?

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm using powershell from SCCM 2012, and I'm really upset because all sccm objects properties are case sensitive, this is really unusual in powershell. Is there anything we can do to make it case insensitive ?

repro:
open sccm console, from top menu click "connect via powershell" then try
`get-CMSite | select sitename` returns nothing
but `get-CMSite |select SiteName` returns all the site names ...

Comment: I tried to reproduce this and it worked both ways, so it seems this was fixed. We currently use System Center Configuration Manager 2012 SP1 CU2. I tried to find out when this was changed but did not find anything official, only this blogpost: http://www.dexterposh.com/2014/04/powershell-sccm-2012-r2-get-client-info.html indicating that it was probably fixed in the SCCM 2012 R2 CU1 update.

Comment: @Syberdoor, OK. FYI I'm using SCCM 2012 R2

Comment: In this case I would try to install the CU1 (or maybe even the latest update for the R2) if that is possible for you, to verify if the blog post is right about the change.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this is out of my scope, I am not allowed to do this.